# What is the right way to conduct an event analysis

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, panel-data, factor-analysis

I have a data set of the daily share prices of 163 companies with the time frame between 2009 and 2016.

I have collected 50 different major economic and geopolitic events that happened during this time frame Ex:(fukushima reactor explosion), and I want to select the 3 most important events.

what is the right statistical approach to do this?

I was thinking about regression analysis with dummy variables or factor analysis.

Would appreciate your opinions.

Comment: I think I am looking for something like "change in stock indices following the event"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the most simple approach may be to measure the difference of all 163 share prices before and after the event (say a week before and a week after). You can normalize them so you will have relative change before and after as percentage of before.

Out of this, 50 163-dimensional vectors will be available $x_{1},\dots x_{50}$ with components $x_{1,1}\dots x_{50,163}$. These may be aggregated with respect to what you understand as the importance, e.g:

- Max average relative change - what increased the prices most
- Min average relative change - what decreased the prices most
- Max average absolute relative change - what changed the prices most
- Span of relative changes - what caused most changes in dynamics among the companies $$\max_{i=1\dots50} \left(\max_{j=1\dots 163 }x_{i,j}-\min_{j=1\dots 163 }x_{i,j}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. what method should I use to measure the "Span of relative changes"?